# Why is my code thinking that both entries are different even if both entries are the same

Tags: c++

the purpose of my code is to get two names from the user and attach them to their own separate array. I think go into a loop where i check each letter and see if they match. I have a Boolean variable that turns to true when the letters are not the same, but it still will not work. I would like to keep doing it this way and this way only.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  bool a{false};
  char name1[100] = " ";
  char name2[100] = " ";
  cout << "Enter the first name:  ";
  cin.getline(name1, 100);
  cout << "Enter the second name:  ";
  cin.getline(name2, 100);
  for (int i = 0; name1[i]; i++) {
    if (name1[i] != name2[i]) {
      bool a{true};
    }
  }
  if (bool a{true})
    cout << "the names are different";
}
}
```

Comment: You have multiple / independent `a` variables declared in different scopes. `if (bool a{true})` you declare a new `a` variable here set it to true then check if its true for the if clause and since it's true you print the message.

Comment: I don't seem to understand if i specifically stated in my first line that a is false, then when the letters don't match a turns true. how am i creating  a new variable.

Comment: Because you're not saying `a = true;`, you're saying `bool a{true};`. That's not assigning to the previous value of `a`, that's creating an entire new variable in a more restricted scope.

Comment: `bool a{true};` should be `a = true;` and `if (bool a{true}){` should be `if  (a) {`